# if condition is not working in c# directly entering into else

Tags: c#

the code below is not working for if condition it directly entering into else.. if i give base value as 2 and power value as 3 it is showing result as 1..... how can i alter this to work properly....

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i, a, result=1;
        int  b;
        Console.WriteLine("enter the base value");
        a=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("enter the power value");
       b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("the vale of {0} to the power {1} is : {2}", a, b, result);
        if(b>0)
        {
            for(i=1; i<=b; i++)
            {
                result=result*a;
            }
        }
        else if (b<0)
        {
            for (i = 1; i <= b; i++)
            {
                result = 1 / (result * a);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            result = 1;

        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Comment: Move `Console.WriteLine("the vale of {0} to the power {1} is : {2}", a, b, result);` to the end of your code, just before `Console.ReadLine();`. You're defining `result=1;`, then asking for values, then showing the values of all your variables and then you make the calculations.

Comment: Please take time to read your code before posting questions on [SO].

Comment: Do you still need help with this?

Comment: thank you for your information...

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you might want to move the code that prints the *result* to happen *after the calculation*?:

```
if(b>0)
{
    for(i=1; i<=b; i++)
    {
        result=result*a;
    }
}
else if (b<0)
{
    for (i = 1; i <= b; i++)
    {
        result = 1 / (result * a);
    }
}
else
{
    result = 1;
}

// happens after the calculation
Console.WriteLine("the vale of {0} to the power {1} is : {2}", a, b, result);
```

Please take some time to learn how to use [a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to debug your code.

Microsoft have an introductory guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2017) and there's a tutorial on a third party site [here](https://csharp.net-tutorials.com/debugging/introduction/).